# Merging hint databases into core

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there a way to add all lemmas in a hint database into core so that I don't have to keep writing `auto with foo` everywhere in a file?

Comment: why don't you define your own tactic for that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need to interleave lemmas from the different database, you can write

```
Hint Resolve 1 => solve [ auto with foo ] : core.
```

Comment: Not quiet what I was looking for, but I'll take what I get.

Comment: Indeed, what you want is not currently possible without writing your own plugin.  However, there is an existing feature request for the feature you want: https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7650#issuecomment-459966243